# FastApi middleware on different folder not working

Tags: python, api, rest, middleware, fastapi

I,m getting this error when I try to run my FastApi api.

> app = cls(app=app, **options)
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I'm trying to add a middleware on other folder separeted from main.py and don't know why isn't working. Otherwise when I add the middleware code into main.py works without problems. Here is my code, thank you for your help and excuse my english.

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi import Request
from routers import rutas
from utils import CheckApiKey
from utils.CheckApiKey import check_api_key

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(CheckApiKey, dispatch=check_api_key) <--- Here calling middleware
app.include_router(rutas.router)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  import uvicorn

  uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, reload=True)
```

Middleware

```
from fastapi import Request

async def check_api_key(request: Request, call_next):    

  print("ok")
  response = await call_next(request) 

  return response
```

Comment: is `CheckApiKey` is a module (a python file) ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu yeah...is the name of the file

Comment: So, that's the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution...I have to create a class that inherite from starlette basehttpmiddleare, like this.

```
from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware


class CheckApiKey(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
 async def dispatch(self, request, call_next):
    print("ok")
    response = await call_next(request)

    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

The **`CheckApiKey`** seems like a ***python module*** in your case and `check_api_key` is the middleware function.

The issue was, the **`add_middleware()`** method expects the first argument as a ***callable function or callable class***. But in your case, you were given a ***module***.

So,

Change your statement as,

```
app.add_middleware(check_api_key)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!...I try your suggestion and I'm getting this error
"TypeError: check_api_key() got an unexpected keyword argument 'app' "

Comment: Can you add your ***complete error traceback*** to OP?

Comment: Found a solution!!..I will post it

Comment: Thanks for your help!